# dpkg error when installing JDK7 on Ubuntu12.04

Tags: java-7, dpkg

**Error message from terminal:**

> Download done.
>   sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u3-linux-i586.tar.gz
>   Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
>   dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   Errors were encountered while processing:
>    oracle-java7-installer

**Install steps:**

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:eugenesan/java`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer`

Could you give me some suggestions how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Ubuntu Documentation on Java](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java):

> A note (hopefully temporary) about the Eugene San PPA for those who are attempting to use it and are having issues: As of the time of this entry, the eugenesan/java PPA is broken. ...

Cleanup the failed PPA installation as mentioned in the above link.

I've installed successfully using the procedure described here:

[Ask Ubuntu: How do I install Oracle Java JDK 7?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55848/how-do-i-install-oracle-java-jdk-7)